# Not able to subscript a value

Tags: swift

I want to setup a subscript so I'm always able to safely use arrays in swift

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let sliceOfArray = array[1...3]

extension Collection {
    subscript(test: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(test) ? self[test] : nil
    }
}

sliceOfArray[test: 0]
```

This gives me the error `Cannot subscript a value of type 'ArraySlice<String>' with an index of type '(test: Int)'`

So how can I get this subscript to run?

Answer (score 0):

> Swift likes to be safe, but one problematic area can be reading from arrays and dictionaries. In the case of dictionaries, reading a missing key will return nil rather than the value you might have expected, but in the case of arrays it’s worse: your app will crash. [More details](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-make-array-access-safer-using-a-custom-subscript)

try like this

```
extension Collection  {
    subscript(safe test: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(test) ? self[test] : nil
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but why do we need the internal parameter name?

Comment: I could constrain the extension in that case. But I don't see what that has to do with the internal parameter name.

Comment: if you add the safe: label to your subscript it will return an Optional of your Element instead of the Element itself. Then, if the Index is in bounds, the Optional will embed your value, but if not, instead of a runtime error, you will get a .none Optional.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a prefix 'test' for your case. This is how subscript syntax works.

This is the valid example:

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let sliceOfArray: ArraySlice<String> = array[1...3]


extension Collection {
    subscript(test test: Index) -> Element? {
        print(test)
        return indices.contains(test) ? self[test] : nil
    }
}
sliceOfArray[test: 2]
```

Documentation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html